# Get all data from session rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

During execution of the web app it stores values in the `session`.
I know that I can get value from it by `session[:some_name]`. But I need to get all the values from it, preferable in hash. Is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: @dan-klasson if just run `session` it returns `#<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x007fede7f02b48>`

Comment: Ah, params is a hash, but session no.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a method `to_hash`

```
session.to_hash
```

Answer (score 1):

Session is not a hash but mimics hash.

You can use `keys` and `[]` to access all elements:

```
session.keys.each do |key|
  p "#{key} => #{session[key]}"
end
```

or use `to_hash`